# document.readyState in Firefox 3.5.x

Tags: javascript, jquery, document, document-ready, readystate

I've a site where I've putten this code to avoid errors:

```
$(function() {
  var fnDocumentReady = function() {
    if(document.readyState != "complete") {
      setTimeout(function () { fnDocumentReady(); }, 300);
      return;
    }

    //do stuff
  };

  fnDocumentReady();
});
```

But I've recently discovered that in FF 3.5 does not execute the code where the "do stuff" is. After analyzing and debbuging I realized that `document.readySate` in FF is always `undefined`. Is there any way to replace this for something else that works similar??

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the *why?* part: [`document.readyState` was added in Firefox 3.6](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/dom/document.readystate).

---

There's no need here for the extra check, jQuery already abstracts detecting when the DOM is ready, all you need is:

```
$(function() {
  //do stuff
});
```

If you're wanting all the images loaded before your code runs, just use `window.onload` instead, like this:

```
$(window).load(function() {
  //do stuff
});
```

Comment: It might stand to reason that this is not a good answer because not everybody uses jQuery, but as it was accepted I can't complain too much. I will say that in Firefox, if your code runs early enough, it can listen to the "DOMContentLoaded" event to figure out when Firefox 3.6 and later would have returned `readyState == 'complete'`

Comment: @Guss - While true, this doesn't address all (especially older) browsers...and the context of the question was all about jQuery :)